# Select query returns field name

Tags: sql, python-3.x, database, postgresql, psycopg2

I am working on a django project where I have a database (postresql) with some tables. I found the following problem: when I'm trying to create a data select query and I want to pass arguments to format the query to the execute function in a tuple, but the fetchall function returns the word passed as an argument to the formatting function in the number of records in the table that have this field.

Table create query:

```
_SQL = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ex04_movies(
        title varchar(64) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
        episode_nb serial PRIMARY KEY,
        opening_crawl text,
        director varchar(32) NOT NULL,
        producer varchar(128) NOT NULL,
        release_date date NOT NULL
        )"""
```

[ex04_table]

[image: 1]

Select query:

```
_SQL = """SELECT %s FROM ex04_movies"""
cursor.execute(_SQL, ('title',))
content = cursor.fetchall()
```

This query returns something like this:
[('title',), ('title',), ('title',), ('title',), ('title',), ('title',), ('title',)]

But when i do this:

```
_SQL = """SELECT %s FROM ex04_movies""" % 'title'
cursor.execute(_SQL)
content = cursor.fetchall()
```

Or this:

```
_SQL = """SELECT title FROM ex04_movies"""
cursor.execute(_SQL)
content = cursor.fetchall()
```

I get correct data:

[('The Phantom Menace',), ('Attack of the Clones',), ('Revenge of the Sith',), ('A New Hope',), ('The Empire Strikes Back',), ('Return of the Jedi',), ('The Force Awakens',)]

How to solve this?

I use psycopg2-binary 2.8.6

Answer (score 1):

SQL identifiers (e.g. names of tables and fields) cannot be passed to the execute() method like query arguments,Change your query string to this and use identifier and format your query :

```
from psycopg2 import sql
_SQL = """SELECT {} FROM ex04_movies"""
cursor.execute(_SQL.format(sql.Identifier('title')))
```

more info [psycopg2 SQL string composition](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html?highlight=identifier#module-psycopg2.sql)